# Convert char to datetime in sql from an odd format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column `createdate char(26)` with data like `2004-01-30-21.29.12.893374`

I want to convert this column to a standard `DATETIME`

However, doing a

```
Convert(DATETIME, createdate,120)
```

is giving this error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I've tried other deviations of the convert value as well, but I feel that the format of the original date value is causing the issue.

I think I need to break the `createdate char(26)` value out using multiple LEFT type statements, but I want to make sure i'm not over complicating this first.

Can any one please help me convert my `char` format to `datetime` in SQL Server 2008?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What Format is that ?

Comment: On the 'createdate' field? It looks like it's YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS.MMMM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Declare @String varchar(50) = '2004-01-30-21.29.12.893374'

Select cast(Left(Stuff(Replace(Stuff(@String,11,1,' '),'.',':'),20,1,'.'),23) as datetime)
```

Returns

```
2004-01-30 21:29:12.893
```

OR for DateTime2

```
Declare @String varchar(50) = '2004-01-30-21.29.12.893374'

Select cast(Stuff(Replace(Stuff(@String,11,1,' '),'.',':'),20,1,'.') as datetime2)
```

Returns

```
2004-01-30 21:29:12.8933740
```

Comment: I know this answer is several years old, but THANK YOU! I have the exact same problem with the exact same format as the OP and this saved my butt!

Answer (score 0):

Fun with `substr`!

```
 select convert(datetime,
     substr(createdate, 1, 10) -- use date part as is
      + ' ' + substr(createdate, 12, 2) -- hours
      + ':' + substr(createdate, 15, 2) -- minutes
      + ':' + substr(createdate, 18, 2) -- seconds
      + '.' + substr(createdate, 21, 3) -- milliseconds (limit to 3 digits)
     , 120) as createDate_DatetimeType
from Table1
```

Comment: You cannot have this fun in `SQL SERVER` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way, without a declared variable or substring:

```
SELECT STUFF(a.fix_punc,11,1,' ') as final_dt
FROM
    (SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(dt_in, 19), '.', ':') + LEFT(RIGHT(dt_in,7),4)
    as fix_punc
    FROM yourtable) as a
```